# Those girls are too kind to refuse

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Those girls are too kind to refuse.

What does it mean:

1) it's hard for **me** to refuse **them** something

2) it's hard for **them** to refuse **me** something (because they are kind)?

3) it can be both ways depending on context?

Comment: It is a rather odd idea.  What does kindness have to do with refusal? Is there some context for this sentence, or did you make it up yourself?

Comment: @James K  It's an example from [M.Swan _PEU_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_English_Usage)

Comment: Seems like you're trying to be tricksy in asking a question about an example from Swan without divulging that in the question.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I wondered myself about the context of the examples in Swan.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow      In Swan's book it has nothing to do with my question which is about its ambiguity. Swan uses it as a counterexample to _too kind a girl to refuse_ construction.

Comment: There is no ambiguity.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow I thought you had agreed that depending on context it might "mean very different things"

Comment: @My Log No, there is no "it" involved. There are **two different** sentences, not a single sentence, and they have completely different meanings. Neither is ambiguous. It is of course true that context determines which meaning makes sense. "He hit me" and "I hit him" are not ambiguous, but mean different things so only context can determine which is appropriate.

Comment: @MV Log: Don't put a critical piece of your question in the title only. As you can see, it has caused confusion.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo   I'm sorry—I thought it's obvious that it might have double meaning and just asked to confirm that.

Comment: @MV Log Your whole premise that two sentences with different pronouns and different word orders are variant expressions of the same thought because they have the same general structure shows a profound ignorance of English grammar. Word order matters in English. Inflections of pronouns matter in English. You keep refering to different orderings of different words as "it." What this singular pronoun shows is that you think "I hit him" and "He hit me" are the same. They are not. Each of your sentences has a single meaning, but the meanings are different.

Comment: @Jeff Morrow   You don't understand what I'm asking about. That's excusable—the infelicitous editing maimed the original question. Read Andrew's answer please—he got it right on the money. **it** = _Those girls are too kind to refuse._

Comment: If you don’t like the way your question was edited, you should fix it to make sure your question is clear for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both work, but without any context, it's more likely you mean your definition #1:

> Those girls are too kind **(for me)** to refuse **(them)**.

This is based on typical sentence structure.  Without any contradictory information, the default is to assume "I" is the subject of "refuse", and "the girls" is the (indirect) object.

> **I** cannot refuse **the girls** (something) (because they are so kind).

In order for it to mean #2, you'd normally specify a different indirect object:

> Those girls are too kind to refuse **me** (something I want).

or else specify a direct object that makes it clear who the subject is:

> Those girls are too kind to refuse (me) **my request**.

Comment: *She was too polite to refuse.*  That kind of statement occurs all the time in spoken English and we rely on context when saying such things and hearing such things. It is valid to tack on a direct object: *She was too polite to refuse **it*** or when the meaning is the other way around, to switch to the passive: *She was too polite **to be refused**.* but in conversation it is often the case that neither of those things happens.

Answer (score 1):

The first means that I find it difficult not to give them what they ask for.

The second means that they find it difficult not to give me what I ask for.

The two sentences are both good English, but mean very different things.

Comment: Not sure why you got that downvote.

Comment: Neither am I, but that is frequently the case.

Comment: Maybe it's because Jeff's answer does not directly answer the question? I have earned downvotes that way. Just a suggestion.

Comment: It does directly answer the question. How does it not do so?

Comment: Probably a drive-by downvoting. The important thing is that the OP seems satisfied.

Comment: The questioner gave an example sentence "Those girls are too kind to refuse." and asked what it meant. He/she then gave three possibilities that he/she could think of. Jeff Morrow confined himself to explaining the meanings of the first two.

Comment: Actually, my answer was not related to what you are discussing at all. I assumed that the question was in the body of the text and was asking whether examples 1 and 2 might meant the same thing and could be interpreted only in context. The OP has since clarified that the question was whether a sentence not even in the body of the question could mean one of two things. This meant my answer missed the intended point. The OP has also since said that the confusion was caused in part by an "infelicitous" edit. I think worrying about why I got a downvote in this case is not worth further concern.